# From quantitative variable regression coefficient to categorical variable regression from summary data

Tags: regression, categorical-data, linear

I am doing a meta-analysis using disease data from published studies and need all the data in one format. I am combining beta coefficient results from papers that have all given relative risks of outcome (heart disease) by comparing the first to the fifth quartile of exposure (fruit intake).

I have a research paper which gives a beta coefficient for linear relationship between an outcome (y) and exposure (x) per SD of exposure. Both y and x are normally distributed variables.

Assuming a linear relationship between y and x, I wish to calculate what would be the estimated coefficient for a relationship between the first quantile (baseline) and fifth quantile of x if it were divided into 5 equal groups (quintiles). The issue is that I only have the the beta and CI for the linear regression of y and x (per SD) from the paper.

Thus in summary, what I have is a beta and CI for a result based upon:

y = ax + c

but I need a the beta and (CIs) for the following (quintiles of x (or five equal parts)) assuming a linear relationship.

y = a1x1 + a2x2 + a3x3 + a4x4 + a5x5 + c

How can convert a coefficient result based upon quantitative independent (exposure or x) variable, to the independent variable being a categorical variable based on quintiles. Assuming there is a linear relationship between y and x is there a way I can calculate this. I don't have the raw data just the regression coefficient and confidence interval (or standard error) result.

Comment: Good question, & it illustrates one of the [problems](http://biostat.mc.vanderbilt.edu/wiki/Main/CatContinuous) with discretizing continuous variables. Do the values of the sample quintiles of fruit intake even match between the studies that reported results that way? (It seems unlikely that the risk of heart disease for a given subject depends much at all on the fruit intake of other subjects who happen to be in the same study.)